# Pine Editor - Study Error, Invalid value of the 'length' argument (0.0) in the "lowest" function. it must be >0

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading, tradingview-api

Im trying to create an RSI divergence indicator and going though some dificulties.

I have searched the web and found that i need to add the nz() command, after adding it im still coming across the error.

```
   //@version=5

indicator("My script")
noColor = color.new(color.white, 100)
Bullcondition = false

//Creating the RSI
rsi= ta.rsi(close,14)

plot(ta.rsi(close,14),color=#7E57C2)
hline(50,linestyle=hline.style_dashed, color=color.new(#787B86, 50))
upperband = hline(30,linestyle=hline.style_dashed, color=#787B86, linewidth = 1)
lowerband = hline(70,linestyle=hline.style_dashed, color=#787B86, linewidth = 1)
fill(upperband, lowerband, color=color.rgb(126, 87, 194, 90), title="RSI Background Fill")


//---------------------------------------------------

pivot_right = input.int(1,minval=1,title="pivot right")
pivot_left = input.int(10,minval=1,title="pivot left")
min_range = input.int(5,minval=1,title="Min range")
max_range = input.int(60,minval=1,title="Max range")

//function to check range in valid
confirm_range(x) =>
    bars =ta.barssince(x == true)
    min_range <= bars and bars <= max_range

//--------------bullish divergence--------------
//strong divergence ( price goes down while RSI goes up)

rsi_lowest = ta.lowest(rsi,50)
bars_lowest = nz(ta.barssince( rsi_lowest == rsi),1)
price_atlowest = low[bars_lowest]
lowest_since = ta.lowest(bars_lowest)

pivot_low = na(ta.pivotlow(rsi,bars_lowest,pivot_right)) ? false : true //checking to see that we are at a lowest point in rsi

Bullcondition := rsi_lowest < rsi and price_atlowest < lowest_since and pivot_low // validating everything is in order

plot(pivot_low ? rsi[pivot_right] : na,offset=-pivot_right, linewidth=1, color=(Bullcondition ? color.yellow : noColor)) // Drawing line in between pivots

    
//pivot_high = na(ta.pivothigh(rsi,pivot_left,pivot_right)) ? false : true //checking to see if we are at pivot high within range defiend
```

Here is my code, hoping to hear from you guys soon.
would appreciate all the help i can get!

Comment: what is the error message you're getting?

Comment: @Daveatt the error message is the tittle

Comment: ah my bad :) 
So it means, whenever your bars_lowest = barssince... == 0, the lowest function doesn't accept it - which is normal as it must be greater than 0.
I understand you're trying to capture the lowest low value since a condition happened right?
I can suggest a dirty hack

```
var float lowest_since = 0
if bars_lowest > 0
    lowest_since := ta.lowest(bars_lowest)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reposting here to format the message

ah my bad :)

So it means, whenever your bars_lowest = barssince... == 0, the lowest function doesn't accept it - which is normal as it must be greater than 0.

I understand you're trying to capture the lowest low value since a condition happened right?

I can suggest a dirty hack

```
var float lowest_since = 0
if bars_lowest > 0
    lowest_since := ta.lowest(bars_lowest)
```

Comment: Thank you that worked!
still have other difficulties that i need to think though. 
But at least that solved that issue! Thanks!